# Find certain pattern of string and replace content , in scraped content from a site

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I have some scraped content like

```
<figure><a href="/fzesny/sample.html">
    <img alt="playerpr120x76" src="/assets/small.jpg"><span class="number">1</span>
    <figcaption>Some Name</figcaption></a>
```

I need to change the href value to "#" and append scraped contents URL in the image src.

```
<a href="">
```

and image tag must have the server URL appended

```
<img src="www.example.com/assets/small.jpg"
```

For image i used

```
$find = "/assets";
$replace = 'http://www.example.com/assets';
echo str_replace($find,$replace,$full_content,$i)
```

How can i remove the href link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the content of your `href` tag with `preg_replace` :

```
$str= '<a href="some/url/idontwant.html">Hey !</a>';
$str = preg_replace("/href=\".*\"/", "href=\"\"", $str);
echo $str;
```

Output : `<a href=""> Hey !</a>`